# Manage relation using Eloquemt ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working with Laravel5.4. I have a user table that have column like `id,introducer_id,company_id,user_role`.

If login user has `company_id` as `1` than fetch all users who has `company_id` as `1` and also fetch whose company is not same as login user but `user_role` is `3`.

I need to fetch users as per the above requirement using Eloquent ORM. So how can I write query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
User::where('company_id', auth()->user()->company_id)
    ->orWhere(function($q) {
        $q->where('company_id', '<>', auth()->user()->company_id)
          ->where('user_role', 3);
    })
    ->get();
```